# Look for a specific Char in a line of code ignoring spaces in SED

Tags: unix, sed

Im new to SED i have been looking around everywhere for the answer! I almost have it but cant figure it out.

```
____= a tab or space
```

**Example Text:**

```
This is sample text - hello.   
______-this is what I want the script to detect only  
Not the - in this one   
______-Just this one
```

**My sed Script**

```
/[^tab]\+-/ {  
s/$/ \\\\/  
}
```

**Output**

```
This is sample text - hello. //  
____-this is what I want the script to detect only //  
Not the - in this one //  
____-Just this one //
```

**Desired Output**

```
This is sample text - hello.  
____-this is what I want the script to detect only //  
Not the - in this one  
____-Just this one //
```

I want my script to see if the first char is a - (ignoring spaces/tabs) and if so then add a space and //

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed '/[^[:blank:]]\+-/s/$/ \/\//' file
This is sample text - hello.
______-this is what I want the script to detect only //
Not the - in this one
______-Just this one //
```